# Запятая после частицы "вот"

Tags: частицы

Известно, что большинство частиц запятыми не выделяется. Это базовое правило знает практически каждый школьник. А что с другими частицами?

---

К сожалению, в справочниках по пунктуации содержится мизерное количество информации по этой теме. Самое главное - обоснование выделения или невыделения той или частицы знаками практически всегда отсутствует.

---

Возьмем для примера частицу **"вот"**. Что пишет "Грамота"?

> **Не требует постановки знаков препинания.** Вот так же отцветем и мы // И отшумим, как гости сада... С. Есенин, Мне грустно на тебя смотреть... Земля гудит под соловьями, // под майским нежится дождем, // а вот солдатик оловянный // на вечный подвиг осужден. Б. Окуджава, Оловянный солдатик моего сына. Вот если бы суд принадлежал обществу как церкви, тогда бы оно знало, кого воротить из отлучения и опять приобщить к себе. Ф. Достоевский, Братья Карамазовы.

---

Не знаю почему, но мой внутренний русист всегда сопротивляется тому, что после **"вот"** не ставят запятую, например тут: *"**Вот** (,) к чему может привести неповиновение!"*

---

В этом предложении логическое ударение падает на **частицу**. Думаю, что вы видите разницу между этим предложением и ,например, "*Вот* это ты зверь!", где на **"вот"** никакого ударения быть не может.

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется. А они, видимо, решили, что на неё не следует ставить ударение.

Comment: "Вот (,) к чему может привести неповиновение!" - мне так кажется, что если бы была запятая, то эту часть можно было убрать без потери согласованности, но "к чему может привести повиновение!" не звучит без вот, тем более с восклицательным знаком, а звучит скорее как вопросительное: "к чему может привести повиновение?", так что тут запятая не нужна. А вот таком примере я бы поставил: Вот, говорили же тебе, что доиграешься!

Comment: То есть "вот" может быть сокращенным "Во́т тебе и на́, во́т тебе на́, во́т те на́ или во́т так та́к! (разг.) — восклицание по поводу чего-н. неожиданного, не соответствующего ожиданиям, удивительного." Хотя я добавил бы еще "Вот тебе" в значении "то-то же" - оборот, который выступает отдельным восклицанием, вроде междометия или типа того. Ну или вообще ставить восклицательный знак после такого: Вот!

Comment: В общем чаще восклицательным разбивается Вот! блабла. Либо: "Ну вот, вы меня опять собьете с пути," - можно сократить до вот. И вот Даль:
Междомет. вона, вот еще, вот-те-на, эко, эхма. То есть, у ВОТ есть междометия. Или вот Крылов:...а чтобы тебе не так скучно было, то вот, возьми этот рубль... Не знаю, есть ли смысл в том, что тут не чисто вот, а "то вот", мне кажется можно было бы и без то: "а чтобы тебе не так скучно было, вот(=на или ну), возьми этот рубль"

Comment: @user190920 к чему может привести-то? какая-то неполнота информации. Если хотя бы И добавить, то может и будет звучать: к чему И может привести неповиновение. А без И нет предиката - условия, то есть того собственно о чём говорят, потому что к чему? - это вопрос, а это части СПП или еще какая-то второстепенная конструкция.

Comment: Спросите лучше у ИРЯ, почему они так решили, а потом расскажете.

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827513.html

Answer (score 0):

**Вот** указательная частица, обычно тире ставится перед ней, а не запятая после:

```
Обезглавливание - вот к чему может привести неповиновение!
Обезглавливание. Вот к чему может привести неповиновение!
```

Согласитесь, здесь уже не хочется запятую втыкать.

А тут вообще не хочется:

```
Вот почему я ушел.
```